# Where to place frameworks and deal with framework clones in your repo?

Tags: git, github, frameworks

So I am creating a HTML5 game using photonstorm/phaser and I have created a github repo for my game project. I've cloned photonstorm/phaser from github into my project (as I've done with other projects), and went to git push to github and realized that git wants to push the included phaser files. I noticed in the past I never really thought about it, but is the directory of a project really the best place to download and place a framework like phaser? If it is, what do I need to do to make sure it doesn't get uploaded to github along my other code as I don't want to be redundantly uploading code from another project on my github project and it would make it easier to manage the repo on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libraries like these shouldn't be included in your Git repo, you are absolutely right about this.

The (de facto) standard way of including these libraries is by using a tool like `npm` (server-side libraries) or `bower` (client-side libraries).

You basically create a config file for these tools (`package.json` for `npm`, or `bower.json` for `bower`) and then use the tool to install the files locally. The *Phaser* project's documentation has a section on using `npm` or `bower` to include it in your app.

These libraries are then installed to a local folder (`node_modules` or `bower_components`), which you usually ignore in your `.gitignore` file.

People cloning your repo will need to run `npm install` or `bower install` locally to download the libraries.